# How to download object from aws s3 bucket and save it to local computer not on server using php?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

The problem with that code when I am using it will download files on my server where my website is running. How can I download it to my local computer.

```
         
    public function download($bucketName,$folderName)
    {
        try {
            $source = $bucketName.'/'.$folder;
            $dest = 'C:/sync/download/'.$folder;
            $manager = new \Aws\S3\Transfer($this->s3, $source, $dest);
            $manager->transfer();
            return $manager;
            //return true;
        } catch (Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception $e) {
            //echo "There was an error downloading the file.";
            return $e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear. Use `scp` do download from a server to local computer.

Comment: @Marcin,  My Question is, can I download directly aws s3 bucket from server to my local computer using php.

Comment: No, because PHP works on your server, not on your local computer.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin, Is there any method to download my aws s3 bucket directly on my local computer using any sdk, like aws-php-sdk, aws-java-sdk etc.